# Long term storage of ethereum in self-custodial hardware wallet

Tags: ether

If there is an update of token standard (e.g ERC20 token), what need to be done to my ethereum (ether) in my self-custodial wallet and my hardware wallet?  
My thought:
I do not need to do anything even if I leave my ethereum token unattended for ten or more years in a hardware wallet(which I do not update for ten or more years). I only need to keep the private key safe. Is my thought correct? Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you correctly understood.
Your assets are as safe as your keys or seed phrase. Keep laminated paper copies of your private keys or seed phrase in fireproof safes on multiple locations and you can just HODL until you decide to participate.

I personally engraved them by myself on stainless steel, it should last a few centuries if no chlorhydrique acid rain happens...

But don't forget that you can use your assets like in eth2 stacking or lend them instead of letting them do nothing.

Comment: My thought: owning ethereum can be interpreted as owning the ledger record entry in the  blockchain and the entry is signed by my private key. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes you can phrase it like that. You must own the private key matching the account address to be able to sign an outgoing transaction for this account.